# pickle load causes supervisord to restart in my Azure VMs only

Tags: linux, python-3.x, pickle, supervisord

I have 15 VMs running this code. 10 are in Rackspace Hyper-Vs and 5 are in Azure. These VMs are built identical to each other (versioning, packages, etc). My 10 Rackspace VMs have no issue running the pickle function, but the 5 I built in Azure randomly restart supervisord every 15 seconds. I know it is my pickle load because I can comment out the load portion of the code and it no longer restarts supervisord.

I have already tried to git my code again, and I have even replace a the copies of the dat files.

Code Below has been generalized.

```
    self.__loadPickFiles() #is part of another def

def __loadPickFiles(self):


    fn1Directory = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)), 'dir1',  'dir2', 'dir3', "File Name 1.pickle.dat")
    fn2Directory = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)), 'dir1',  'dir2', 'dir3', "File Name 2.pickle.dat")

    import pickle
    self.fn1p_model = pickle.load(open(fn1Directory, "rb"))
    self.fn2p_model = pickle.load(open(fn2Directory, "rb"))
```

expected result

```
flaskApp:flaskApp_00             RUNNING   pid 2574, uptime 1:37:48
flaskApp:flaskApp_01             RUNNING   pid 2575, uptime 1:37:48
flaskApp:flaskApp_02             RUNNING   pid 2572, uptime 1:37:48
flaskApp:flaskApp_03             RUNNING   pid 2573, uptime 1:37:48

current result (randomly restarts every 15 secs or less)
flaskApp:flaskApp_00             RUNNING   pid 8983, uptime 0:00:12
flaskApp:flaskApp_01             STARTING  
flaskApp:flaskApp_02             STARTING  
flaskApp:flaskApp_03             RUNNING   pid 8984, uptime 0:00:12
```

Comment: I am grasping at straws now because the code works in a Rackspace hypervisor, but not in a Azure VM.
could it be spaces in the file name it is reading? Could it be file name length?
Here is generalized file name using same number and type of characters:
AB5 M2 HQ Replica ABCDEFG v1.pickle.dat

Answer (score 0):

After a couple of weeks of trying to figure out this dilemma, the answer was in the dat file.
The dat file was created in xgboost (written in the top few lines), and I needed to 'pip install xgboost' which was missing from my build instructions.